# JS - split an array string and pass both parts as arguments to a method

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

So, I've got a method to grab particular DIV from x, y coordinates:

```
this.getCell = function (x, y){
      this.index = x + y * this.width;
      return this.cells[this.index];
}
```

I want to use my method with another one:

```
this.computeCellNextState = function(x, y){

      var nearbies = ['x-1,y-1','x,y-1','x+1,y-1'];
      var splitter = nearbies[0].split(',');

      console.log(this.getCell(splitter[0],splitter[1])); // returns undefined

}
```

What I want to achieve:

```
this.getCell(x-1,y-1)

x-1,y-1 are from nearbies[0]
```

I want to split one string of 'nearbies' and use as 2 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`'x-1,y-1'` etc are just strings, they don't mean anything for `getCell`. You have to work with actual expressions in `computeNextState`, e.g.

```
this.computeCellNextState = function(x, y){

      var nearbies = [[x-1,y-1],[x,y-1],[x+1,y-1]];

      console.log(this.getCell(...nearbies[0]))

}
```

Comment: That's what I missed, rookie mistake. Thank you!